# Jquery UI css not being added to my project after bundling

Tags: c#, css, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I added jquery ui to my small project but the css is not getting added.

The following bundle is for the css:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

With the following in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
```

Global.asax.cs has BundleConfig set to register on Application_Start()....

I cleared my firefox cache out, but im still only getting the default bootstrap.css and site.css on my page.

Any ideas? Im not sure what else to check here, ive got some dialogs im playing with for crud functionality and they have no style.

Comment: Try changing the name of your bundle.

Comment: I've tried that before but to no avail.

Comment: please check if css files are in provided catalogue in your project (`"/Content/themes/base/"`) and I understand that your `"~/Content/css"` bundle is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

View the source of in your browser and make sure that the CSS isn't minified. I deployed in IIS 7 and the bundle was picking up the minified CSS, which IIS didnt like.

Comment: No css was getting added when I viewed my source. I ended up adding it the old fashion way without bundling and it picked it up. Weird error since I had other bundles that were picked up.

Answer (score 0):

While bundling didnt end up working, I was able to do it the old fashion way with  tags, picking the Jquery ui css files I wanted to use.